# how to access object attributes in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, object, attributes

Hey i wanna access object attributes in AS3 , i have array of many object for example teacher , student 
 i need code how access attributes  for teacher ,

```
        private function init():void
        {
          //action is ArrayCollection contains teacher object and student object
            action=new ArrayCollection();
            action=srv.getData(id);
        }
```

my problem is here when fetch ArrayCollection in List

```
<s:List id="list"  dataProvider="{action}">
<s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <s:IconItemRenderer labelField="What should I write ?? to access Teacher Name"/>
    </fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking around on the internet first? Plenty of resources should be available.

Comment: all resource how access directly to attribute not access object attribute
for example array of String or int so i can access by name attribute

 <s:IconItemRenderer labelField="name"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I a solved problem :)

change labelField to label ...

and write in label={data.teacher.name}

```
<s:List id="list2" dataProvider="{action}">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer label="{data.teacher.Name}" />
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```